# How do I save a scratch file in IntelliJ 14

Tags: intellij-idea

I have scratch file. I developed something useful. Now I know how should I name file, the content will reside in.

Is it possible to convert scratch file to normal file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save it by pressing **F5**

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206834865-Is-there-a-Save-Scratch-File-As-?flash_digest=3f8ff00c01b15c180184ef92750a3ccbe3d4a040

Comment: *F5* as copy refactoring

Comment: just did that (i.e. Refactor to move file to project dir) and it broke the auto-save response history feature.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>It is not possible now.</strike> Create new file and copy content of scratch file there.

Answer (score 0):

Files should be here :

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.3\consoles
```